# How to use preg_match_all search if HTML source contains given URL?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to find all `href` tags that include my URL in any html source.

I used this code:

```
preg_match_all("'<a.*?href=\"(http[s]*://[^>\"]*?)\"[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>'si", $target_source, $matches);
```

Example, I try to find a href tags that include `http://www.emrekadan.com`

How can I do it ?

Comment: are you just looking for the string "http://www.emrekadan.com" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use PHP's [`DOM`](http://php.net/dom) Parser for this purpose. This may seem harder than regex, but it's actually a lot more easier and is the *correct* way to parse HTML.

```
$url = 'WEBSITE_TO_SEARCH_FOR';
$searchstring = 'YOUR_SEARCH_STRING';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$result = array();

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if(stripos($href, $searchstring) !== FALSE) {
        $result[] = $href;
    }
}

if(!empty($result)) print_r($result);
```

Explanation:

- Loads the given URL using [`loadHTMLfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) method
- Finds all `<a>` tags and loops through them
- Uses [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) to case-insensitively check if the href contains the given search term
- If it does, it's pushed into the `$result` array

Note: If an empty string is passed as the filename or an empty file is named, a warning will be generated. I've used `@` to hide that message, but it's generally regarded as a bad practice. You can add additional checks to make sure the URL exists before trying to load it.

Comment: @AmalMurali As the OP stated, it's faster and easier. `+1` ;-)